# Interrupt JS in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, qunit

I'm creating an automated test framework based on QUnit, and I'd like to be able to kill a test if it takes too long (time it out). Now, my current implementation is one that is pretty simple: On the starting of a test, I setup a timer and wait. If the test hasn't finished by then, I mark it as failed and reload the `<iframe>` the tests are running in.

This works great if it is waiting for an AJAX call, or an asynchronous test never comes back. However, the `setTimeout` function will always run after the current execution thread, so if a test gets into an infinite loop, or is just taking too long in its standard execution, it won't really stop it, and instead just sits and waits for its turn without interrupting it. **Is there any way to cancel the execution of code in a child `<iframe>` (which is in the same domain) even if it gets stuck in a loop?**

Answer (score 0):

Define your timer in the parent window - when the IFrame loads, get it to start the timer in the parent window - when the timer runs out get the parent window to re-load the IFrame.

In your parent page

```
<script> 

function startTimer(duration) {     
    setTimeout("timedOut()",duration);
} 

function timedOut() {
       // handle time out
}

</script>  

<iframe id=myFrame></iframe>
```

In your IFrame

```
<script> 
    parent.startTimer(duration);
</script>
```

Each page runs on a different thread so it *should* work for you, but there are things that will lock-up the entire browser system (infinite loops/infinite recursion) where you'll have to get the task manager involved to re-start the browser, but it should cover the bulk of cases.

Comment: "*Each page runs on a different thread*" - that depends on the browser.

Comment: This is what I have currently, but the infinite loop/long code execution case is the one that I want to be able to handle better. Also, as far as different pages running in different 'threads', this is likely browser specific, and I'd like something browser independent. Additionally, would browsers count separate frames as different pages, or run them in the same 'thread'?

Comment: You're really going to struggle with that mate - it's something even the browsers have issues with - let me have a play around with it.